# Calculate elements in CSV file

Tags: ruby, csv

I am new to Ruby and now I have an issue while I try to calculate some elements.

I've got 6 CSV files with the same headers and the question is how to find the total amount of payments for each payed month.

`01-test.csv`

```
Payment date,Payable month,House,Apartment,Amount of payment
2014-09-14,2014-08,Panel,84,5839.77
2014-09-14,2014-08,Brick,118,4251.63
2014-09-14,2014-08,Brick,97,471.5
2014-09-14,2014-08,Panel,53,236.22
2014-09-14,2014-08,Panel,83,4220.77
.......
```

`02-test.csv`

```
Payment date,Payable month,House,Apartment,Amount of payment
2014-10-01,2014-08,Brick,34,1522.59
2014-10-01,2014-08,Brick,117,1285.57
2014-10-01,2014-08,Brick,136,1925.97
2014-10-01,2014-08,Brick,24,1032.95
2014-10-01,2014-08,Brick,113,957.01
.......
```

Here is my code:

```
def create_month_array(payments)
    months = []
    months = payments.uniq { |a| a[:payed_for]
    months
end
def payed_for_each_month(payments, months)
    sums = Array.new(months.length){|a| a = 0}
    months.each{|a|
        if(a[:payed_for] == payments.each{|x| x[:payed_for]})
           .....
        end
        }

    p sum
    sum.round(2)

end
```

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Is `"2014-08"` a "payed month"? Do you want totals for each file or for all files combined?

Comment: When giving an example, please adhere to the following: 1. All input objects should be complete (no "...") so readers can run code against the data. 2. Make the example as small as possible while keeping the essence of the question (e.g., here two smaller CSV files). 3 Show the desired or expected result as a Ruby object. (If the object is large just show enough to indicate its contents.) 4. Assign a variable to each object (e.g., `arr = [1,2,3]`). That way readers don't have to define those objects in answers and comments. Here you can't easily do #4 because you are displaying file images.

Comment: You say you have an issue.  What exactly is the issue?  Are you not seeing the result you expect?  Is so, what are you seeing instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the data were read from files into strings.

```
str1 =<<_
2014-09-14,2014-08,Panel,84,5839.77
2014-09-14,2014-08,Brick,118,4251.63
2014-09-14,2014-09,Brick,97,471.5
2014-09-14,2014-10,Panel,53,236.22
2014-09-14,2014-10,Panel,83,4220.77
_
str2 =<<_
2014-10-01,2014-08,Brick,34,1522.59
2014-10-01,2014-09,Brick,117,1285.57
2014-10-01,2014-09,Brick,136,1925.97
2014-10-01,2014-10,Brick,24,1032.95
2014-10-01,2014-11,Brick,113,957.01
_
```

We can then combine the strings into a single string, convert it an array of lines and then use a *counting hash* to aggregate values for each payable month, which I assume to be the values of the second field. See [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new), specifically when `new` is assigned an argument equal to the *default value* (here `0`).

```
(str1 + str2).lines.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |line,h|
  _, payable_month, _, _, amount = line.split(',')
  h[payable_month] += amount.to_f
end
  #=> {"2014-08"=>11613.990000000002, (5839.77 +  4251.63 + 1522.59)
  #    "2014-09"=>3683.04,            ( 471.5  +  1285.57 + 1925.97)
  #    "2014-10"=>5489.9400000000005, ( 236.22 +  4220.77 + 1032.95)
  #    "2014-11"=>957.01}             ( 957.01)
```

If a hash `h` is defined

```
h = Hash.new(0)
```

Ruby expands `h[payable_month] += amount.to_f` to

```
h[payable_month] = h[payable_month] + amount.to_f
```

If `h` has no key `payable_month`, `h[payable_month]` on the right of the equality sign returns the default value. Hence,

```
h[payable_month] = 0 + amount.to_f
  #=> amount.to_f
```

Note we could have alternatively written

```
(str1.lines + str2.lines).each_with_object(Hash.new(0))...
```

or we could have read each file line-by-line and written all those lines to one file.

Answer (score 1):

To combine all CSV data across multiple files use the following:

```
csv_files = ["01-test.csv", "02-test.csv", "03-test.csv", "04-test.csv", "05-test.csv", "06-test.csv"]

csv_data = CSV.generate(headers: :first_row) do |csv|
  csv << CSV.open(csv_files.first).readline

  csv_files.each do |csv_file|
    CSV.read(csv_file)[1..-1].each { |row| csv << row }
  end
end
```

To then to the calculate the sum of each `"Payable month"` (or `"Payment date"`,
it was not clear which was the *payed month*), you do the following

1. Interpret the data, using Ruby's CSV library

   ```
   data = CSV.parse(csv_data, headers: true)
   ```
2. Group the data by the *payed month*

   ```
   month_array = data.group_by { |row| row["Payable month"] }
   # month_array = data.group_by { |row| row["Payment date"][0..6] }
   ```

   *Chose either line and comment out the other*
3. For each `month` get the sum/`reduce` of all the `"Amount of payment"` into a
   total for that month within our collection of `totals`

   ```
   payed_for_each_month = month_array.each_with_object({}) do |(month, rows), totals|
     totals[month] = rows.reduce(0.0) { |sum, row| sum + row["Amount of payment"].to_f }
   end
   ```

This produces the final result with the presented data

```
payed_for_each_month
# => {"2014-08"=>21743.98}
```

*If `"Payment date"` month was used instead the totals would produce the following:*

```
month_array = data.group_by { |row| row["Payment date"][0..6] }
# ...
payed_for_each_month
# => {"2014-09"=>15019.890000000001, 
#     "2014-10"=>6724.09}
```

All the code together:

```
data = CSV.parse(csv_data, headers: true)

month_array = data.group_by { |row| row["Payable month"] }
# month_array = data.group_by { |row| row["Payment date"][0..6] }

payed_for_each_month = month_array.each_with_object({}) do |(month, rows), totals|
  totals[month] = rows.reduce(0.0) { |sum, row| sum + row["Amount of payment"].to_f }
end

payed_for_each_month
# => {"2014-08"=>21743.98}
```

**References:**

- [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)
- [`reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)
- [`each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object)